# MySQL range between dates: First order + 6 months

Tags: mysql, date

I'm using MySQL Workbench to run my query.

I want to run a couple of different date queries, I don't know if it's possible in SQL.

1)  Run the report from the first date in the system to X date.
How can I find what the first orderID or date is as part of the calculations?
I know that if I have the date to begin with, I can use:
`where T5.date_purchased BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'`   OR:
`where T5.date_purchased BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

**UPDATE**
----- Query 2 has been answered (although open to any improvement) -----

2)  Run the report from the first time a product shows up, to + 6 months (to see it's first 6 months of order) ie:  Widget 1 (first order) + 6 months from order date.  Something like:
`where widget=widgetID AND date between widget1's first purchase and +6 months`

**Update:**  This doesn't work, however this is somewhat of what I was thinking:
`where (T3.products_id = 39) and DATE_ADD((T1.products_date_added), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

I would use my `P3.products_date_added,` however, I don't know how to use it as part of the above, correctly.

Are either of these possible, I know how to pull the records when I know the date, I just don't know if it can be done with 'date unknown' or if I have to run a "pre-report" first.  Or is it a post processing filter in excel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like it would be possible but without knowing anything about your table structure and seeing some sample data with expected output it is hard to actually help you.

Comment: @jpw I was thinking something along the lines of:  `where (T3.products_id = 39) and DATE_ADD((T1.products_date_added), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` this would give me from the first order July 2014 to January 2015, however I can't get it to work.  I keep getting all dates from Jul to now.  It's part of a larger query that pulls data across a number of tables.

Comment: Try doing it like `date_purchased between products_date_added and DATE_ADD((T1.products_date_added), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` maybe?

Comment: @jpw Bingo (I think).  A slight tweak:  `where (T3.products_id = 39) and T5.date_purchased between T1.products_date_added and DATE_ADD((T1.products_date_added), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`  Just double checking with a couple of other IDs, to confirm.

Comment: @jpw It does work, is there a way to tweak it even further so I can add 2 products in, so I can compare the first 6 months of each.  So, PID - 13 & 18?

Comment: I can't say really; there's too little information for me to give any answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering problem #2:**

> 2) Run the report from the first time a product shows up, to + 6 months (to see it's first 6 months of order) ie: Widget 1 (first order) + 6 months from order date. Something like:
>   `where widget=widgetID AND date between widget1's first purchase and +6 months`

**Answer:**

```
-- Use for specific comparisons of products OR for the first X months of sales
        where (T3.products_id = 39) and T5.date_purchased between T1.products_date_added and DATE_ADD((T1.products_date_added), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    --  This results in PID: release: 10th July, +2 months; 10th Sep. 31 units.

    OR
    -- (T3.products_id = 11 or T3.products_id = 39) gives the results of the 2 product orders from release date to the first 2 months of each
    -- (T3.products_id) gives all products, their first 2 months of release
    -- (T3.products_id = 39) gives specific product release sales

-- Inspired by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788691/mysql-range-between-dates-first-order-6-months?noredirect=1#comment45853546_28788691
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for your solution, try and run 2 separate queries:
- ONE for finding the date of first order
- then calculate +6 months from query 1 result
- AND the second one to get the purchases BETWEEN both dates

Comment: thank you.  I've updated a line that I've come across, but it doesn't work.  I'd rather not have to run pre-reports, as the hope is to call the query from a bat file as part of a processing batch. :)  Thank you.